# Invalid Verb Error While Executing Batch File

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have been trying to execute a batch file.  The logic which I'm trying is that is if memory (working set Private) of a service exceeds a particular value the service should get restarted.

However, I'm getting error as invalid verb when I try to execute this bat file:

```
@Echo OFF

SET    "SERVICE=Themes"
SET /A "MAXUSAGE=401400"
SET /A "INTERVAL=5"

:LOOP 
For /F %%P in ('wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process where      Name="cmd" get WorkingSetPrivate /value ^| FINDSTR "[0-9]"') do (
IF %%P GTR %MAXUSAGE% (
    Echo [%TIME:~0,8%] CPU Usage: %%P%% Reached the limit: %MAXUSAGE%%%
    Echo Restarting %SERVICE% ...
     SC STOP  "%SERVICE%" 1>NUL
    SC START "%SERVICE%" 1>NUL
    Echo Service restarted.
) ELSE (
     Echo [%TIME:~0,8%] CPU Usage: %%P%%
)
)
Ping -n %INTERVAL% Localhost >NUL
GOTO :LOOP     `
```

I'm new to this type of coding. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no reason to SHOUT AT US. We all read very well, so you don't need to SHOUT your questions. Typing your question in ALL CAPS (particularly the title) will not get you an answer any sooner, it makes your question more difficult to read, and it's rude and annoying. If you scan through the main questions page and count how many question titles appear in ALL CAPS, do you see many others except yours? Please be polite and STOP YELLING AT US. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry 
I'll keep this thing in mind in future

Comment: I would be able to help you further if you were to provide a proper explanation of your actual task, all you have here is a copied previous answer which has been partially changed. There are other problems with your code beyond that which is reporting the error; they will also need fixing.

Comment: My task is to restart a particular service if its memory consumption exceeds a particular value say 700 mb
So i'm trying to write a batch file to restart that service when memory consumption reaches its threshold

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic command line which should indicate to you a fix for your problem:

```dos
For /F "Skip=1 UseBackQ" %A In (`wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData
_PerfProc_Process where "name='cmd'" get workingsetprivate`) Do @For %B In (%A) Do @Echo([%B]
```

UseBackQ is your clue…

Comment: i tried replacing the for line as
    For /F "Skip=1 UseBackQ" %%P In (`wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData
_PerfProc_Process where "name='cmd'" get workingsetprivate`)
  but i get the same error as invalid verb

Comment: UseBackQ means Use Back Quotes, I used them, you haven't. Please check my answer, and run the line exactly as a have from a command window. When you've done that, double up the percents and write it in a batch file, starting it with `@Echo Off` and ending it with a `Pause`. When you've seen that it works, make your alterations.